# Cypress, retrying against element thats no longer attached to the DOM

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I'm currently using cypress to test that a 'pill' element is added on the frontend when the data gets to a particular state.

- I identify the row being targeted using `cy.contains()`
- I then chain it with `parents('tr').contains('<string>')` to identify that the pill I want is being added

The only problem is because the cleanup logic that happens prior to the test triggers a third party webhook that my app responds to, sometimes the row I'm targeting gets removed (after its been found using the first `cy.contains()` command) and then re-added to the DOM before it reaches its final state.

I *believe* this is then what causes the second part to fail - cypress appears not to have realised its been detached from the DOM and times out expecting to find my `<string>` on the detached node.

The full chain looks something like this

```
cy.get('table')
  .find('tr') // Get all the rows
  .contains('stringToIdentifyMyTableRow') // Get the text in the specific row I care about
  .parents('tr') // broaden scope to whole row
  .contains('pillString') // Find text I'm looking for
```

It seems like its *found* everything after the `.parents('tr')` command so its not bothering to retry, even when they are actually detached from the DOM - rather its continuing to look for the `pillString` in the detached node. What I'd like it to happen is for cypress to continually retry the whole chain until the application reaches its intended state.

Comment: What version of Cypress are you using?

Comment: I am using version 11.2

Comment: Try updating to the latest version 12. It has a new feature that retries when elements are detached from the DOM https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#12-0-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating to the latest version 12. It has a new feature that retries when elements are detached from the DOM docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#12-0-0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try eliminating the `.parents('tr')` step

```js
cy.get('table')
  .contains('tr', 'stringToIdentifyMyTableRow')  
  .contains('pillString')                       // should be pill cell
```

It's easy to get detached errors with React because of the frequent re-render of components.

Your test has no action to cause a re-render, if the webhook is doing it then you need a way to start the test after the webhook has run.